# NServiceBus messages with properties of base type

Tags: .net, wcf, nservicebus

We have developed a WCF web service with the contract similar to following:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "XXX")]
public interface ISynchronization
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void ProcessEntities(List<BaseEntity> entities);
}
```

It does it's work great and is easy to extend by making use of `knowntypes` configuration for `BaseEntity` under `datacontractserializer` in the configuration file.

It is now required to make use of reliable message delivery with `NServiceBus` and I need to come up with appropriate message format, capable of entities transportation in a generic way.

I'm new to `NServiceBus`, but from what I've understood, default NSB serializer won't take care about polymorphism and I'm stuck with command-per-entity scenario.

The mentioned above isn't any kind of wheel reinvention and there must be an elegant solution to it.

What are the possible drawbacks of using DataContractSerializer instead of NSB's native one?

---

**EDIT (inheritance test as a reply to Ramon's answer)**

I've used one of the [NSB test projects](https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/tree/master/IntegrationTests/WcfIntegration) and changed the CancelOrder like following:

```
public class CancelOrder : IMessage
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public List<EntityBase> Entities { get; set; }
}

[KnownType(typeof(Employee))]
[KnownType(typeof(Organization))] //Serialization fails otherwise
public class EntityBase
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Employee : EntityBase {
    public override string Name {get{ return "Employee"; }}
    public string EmployeeProperty {get{ return "Employee Property Value"; }}
}

public class Organization : EntityBase
{
    public override string Name {get{ return "Organization"; }}
    public string OrganizationProperty {get { return "Organization Property Value"; }}
}
```

`EntityBase` (not abstract - that also brakes the serialization) has single virtual property `Name` for ease of testing.

The test client is sending a `CancelOrder` with Entities list populated with `Employee` and `Organization`:

```
 var message = new CancelOrder
               {
                 OrderId = orderId++,
                 Entities = new List<EntityBase>
                 {
                   new Employee(), 
                   new Organization()
                 }
               };

 var returnCode = client.Process(message);
```

Once delivered to the server, they are no more then `EntityBase` types (`message.Entities[0] as Employee == null`)

[image: Quick Watch at the Server]

Comment: Not entirely clear why you would want to have such flexible messages. Your interface suggests that you are building your own kind of 'replication' on top of messaging.


Why not have a message per entity? Why do you want to batch them in a single message? A single message has size contraints.

Comment: I'm processing flat list of entities of the same type(list size will be defined as a result of performance testing). Tomorrow, if I need to add an extra entity, I'll only register the corresponding `knownType` for `BaseEntity` and DCS will handle this. The rest is done via IoC container that initializes repositories next mapped to entity type. Would you say that a message per entity is a better option (a single BaseEntity property within `SyncronizeCommand` in your answer), why?

Comment: If the processing for all new types is exactly the same then this could work but if the processing is different then its probably best to put them in different messages types.

Also, I would not do batching in a message unless its because of transactional boundaries (all items must succeed or none will).

If this is a sort of data replication then this is an anti-pattern. Don't build replication on top of messaging. Use SQL Service replication for that or other similar low-level options.

Comment: it's an integration. provisioning one system with data from another system. can be done on demand or as a scheduled routine.

Comment: Is this an integration with an external system? Isn't it possible to use the concept of a composite UI to only integrate the data in the UI and not keeping a copy of that data in another system its database?

Comment: Unfortunately it is not possible

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92497/discussion-between-andrew-and-ramon-smits).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your interface can be translated to the following messages:

```
public class SynchronizeCommand : IMessage
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public List<EntityBase> Entities { get; set; }
}

[KnownType(typeof(Employee))] // Required for WCF, not the Json serializer
[KnownType(typeof(Organization))]
public class EntityBase
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Employee : EntityBase {
    public override string Name {get{ return "Employee"; }}
    public string EmployeeProperty {get{ return "Employee Property Value"; }}
}

public class Organization : EntityBase
{
    public override string Name {get{ return "Organization"; }}
    public string OrganizationProperty {get { return "Organization Property Value"; }}
}
```

The NServiceBus XML serializer cannot serialize this but the Json serializer does.

The polymorphism restriction that you mention is about the message type not its properties.

If you want polymorphic behavior in the type of handlers that you want to get triggered then you cannot use multiple inheritance with classes. Only interfaces are allowed as those are the only types that allow multiple inheritance.

Data contract serializer cons

- Cannot serialize interfaces, needs a class
- You need to use the DataContractSerializer on all your endpoints
- The NServiceBus serializer is less flexible to keep message contracts simple
- XML is less readable

Data contract serializer pros

- Better suited for integration purposes
- Supports complex data like graphs with cyclic references

Comment: thank you for your answer. Please check my `Edit` part in the original question

Comment: I'm sorry but I accidentally tested with the Json serializer instead of the xml serializer.

Comment: Json serialize did it's job. Could you please update your answer (by also including the `KnownType` attribute for BaseEntity) so that it is a complete solution for anyone else having same problem and I'll accept the answer. Many thanks!

Comment: KnownType is not required for Json.

Comment: Doesn't work for me without specifying the `KnownTypes`

Comment: are we both talking about the same serializer? `configuration.UseSerialization<JsonSerializer>();`